# Arrangement of the word 'Success'

Tags: combinatorics

Number of ways the word 'Success' can be arranged, such that no two S's and C's are together.

Comment: Did you intend to write the word "Success" with that exact capitalization? What I mean is, are all of the `s`'s to be considered interchangeable?

Comment: No, ignore the capitalization.

Answer (score 7):

These problems quickly
get out of hand if the words are long and there are lots of multiple letters.
Here is a sophisticated solution that uses ideas from *algebraic combinatorics*.
I learned it from Jair Taylor's [wonderful answer here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129451/find-the-number-of-arrangements-of-k-mbox-1s-k-mbox-2s-cdots/129802#129802)
See [this question also.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76213/how-many-arrangements-of-a-2b-3c-4d-5e-have-no-identical-consecutive-lett)

Define polynomials for $k\geq 1$ by  $q_k(x) =
\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{(-1)^{i-k}}{i!} {k-1 \choose i-1}x^i$. Here are the first few
polynomials:
$$q_1(x)=x,\quad q_2(x)=x^2/2-x,\quad q_3(x)=x^3/6-x^2+x.$$

The number of permutations with no equal  neighbors, using
an alphabet with frequencies $k_1,k_2,\dots$ is:

> $$\int_0^\infty \prod_j q_{k_j}(x)\,  e^{-x}\,dx.$$

For the "success" problem, the product of the $q$ functions is
$$ q_3(x)\, q_2(x)\, q_1(x)^2=(x^3/6-x^2+x)(x^2/2-x)x^2 =
x^7/12-2x^6/3+3x^5/2-x^4,$$

and performing the integral gives the answer 96.

Answer (score 4):

We start with all  arrangements
with non-consecutive "S"s, then subtract
those where the "C"s are together.

That is, we begin with the  arrangements
with non-consecutive "S"s over the
alphabet {S,U,C,C,E,S,S} and then subtract the arrangements
with non-consecutive "S"s over the
alphabet {S,U,CC,E,S,S}. Note the double "C" in the
second alphabet.

Using the formula  from [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111828/some-questions-about-combinations/162436#162436), we get
$${5\choose 3}{4!\over 2!}-{4\choose 3}{3!}=120-24=96. \ \ \ \ $$

Comment: 120 - 24* = 96.

Comment: @IshaanSingh Thanks, I've corrected it.

Answer (score 4):

The total number of permutation of letters (T)= $\frac{7!}{2!3!}$
With two `cc` together (A)= $\frac{6!}{2!}$
With three `ss` together (B)=  $\frac{6!}{2!} - \frac{5!}{2!}$
With both `ss` and `cc` together (C)= $5! - 4!$
Answer = T - A - B + C = 96

**EDIT::**
The number of unique permutation of consecutive $t-1$ $s$'es out of $t$ $s$'es in total of $n$ elements is given by $(n-(t-1))! - (n -t)!$ and this does not include $t$ s'es.

Matlab code for answer:

```
P = unique(perms(['s' 'u' 'c' 'c' 'e' 's' 's']), 'rows');
count = 0;
for i = 1:length(P)
    for j = 1:6
        if P(i,j) == P(i,j+1)
            count = count+1;
            break;
        end
    end
end
disp([length(P), count, length(P)-count]);
```

Comment: Dunno what's wrong with my logic but I got 72. Got $\frac{6!}{3!} $,$\frac{6!}{2!} - \frac{5!2!}{2!}$ and $5! - 4!2!$

Comment: why did you multiply by 2! ??

Comment: for e.g to find at least two s together I permute s,u,c,c,e,ss then I subtract the number of permutations with s and ss are together. and the 2! means I'm accounting for the permutation of s and ss when they are counted as a single object...

Comment: Let there be $n$ elements, $t$ being identical and rest unique.  The no of arrangements of $t-1$ consecutive identical elements, for some strange reasons seems to be$(n-(t-1))! - (n-t)!$

Comment: @Dan try for $|a|b|s|s|$ and $|a|s|s|s|$ the cases where you get consecutive $ss$

Answer (score 0):

Place the letters S separated by some space. This gives four possible spaces for the remaining letters including the ends. Choose 2 of these spaces for the C letters; that is 6 possibilities. If the C letters are placed at the ends are two ways to place the U and E.
The configuration would look like CSXSXSC. There are thus 2 possibilities. If only one C is at an end, the other is interior say CSCSXS then we can place the U&E in the position of the X and then place the other letter in one of 7 positions for a total of 14 possibilities.
If both C letters are interior then we have SCSCS and so we can place the U in any of 6 positions and then the E in any of 7 positions so we get 42 possibilities. This gives a grand total of 42+4*14+2=100. (I've probably overlooked something.)

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion the answer would be as follows
$$
\frac{7!}{3!\cdot 2!} = 420
$$ ways we can arrange word success

by: Javed Masood - FUUAST

Comment: You did not factor in the condition that the 's' can not repeat next to each other, nor the 'c'.

Answer (score -2):

The total number of permutation of letters (T)= 7! 3!2!

Answer = N!/(N1!*NK!) = 7!/(3!*2!)= 420

The answer from April 22 at 0535 is correct.  the rest are dead wrong.

Comment: This is incorrect, as Willie Wong's comment pointed out on said answer.