# Flag making with 6 vertical stripes

Tags: combinatorics

I was preparing for my Engineering entrance exam and got across this question.

A flag is to be made with 6 vertical stripes by using colours yellow, blue, green and red in such a way that none of the adjacent stripes have same colour. How many ways is it possible?

I landed up with 12x81 but I tried again and landed with 24x216

Comment: if you explain how you counted we can find possible errors

Comment: @mm-aops first I took yellow in position 1 then 2 then on till 6 later green, red, blue. So 4 colours and 6 different positions. 6x4=24. There was an option given there 24x216 so i thought it might be right.

Comment: Just worked on this same type problem over here:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840965/permutation-combination/842434#842434

Comment: @bobbym ok. But how did u expand ( 1111), that vertical one in end

Comment: Hi; I had to use Mathematica, too tedious to do by hand. You will find more manageable solutions there too.

Comment: @user3627194 Do you have to use all the colors?

Comment: @bobbym some or all colors. Options here are 12x18, 24x216, 16x108. I don't know which is correct. Also if you know what type of sums are these then please tell me. I would like to study them in deep.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15257/discussion-between-bobbym-and-user3627194).

Comment: @bobbym I don't have that much reputation to chat. Email?

Comment: @bobbym what are these types of sums called?

Comment: user3627194 I am sorry, I do not know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what you do is you consider the first strip - its colour can be chosen out of all possible $4$. once you chose the colour of the first one you only have $3$ choices for the second one - cause it can't be the same which gives you $4 \cdot 3$ possibilities for the first two stripes. continuing this way you end up with $4 \cdot 3^5$ ways

Comment: There's no option as such there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's correct unless you have extra assumptions in your problem - i.e. all the colors have to be used

Comment: I agree that is correct. It also is one of his options of 12 x 81.

Answer (score 0):

It must be 12 x 81 for sure. It is not that hard. 
For six strips the first can be filled up in 4 ways, i.e,  any one of the colours ; and the next can be filled in 3 ways since the colour used in the first strip cannot be used. The third can be filled up again in 3 ways since the colour to the left cannot be used. And this goes on till the last strip.  So we finally get 4 x 3^5. Equivalent to 12 x 81.